# Android - ORMlite vs. ActiveAndroid differences?

Tags: android, orm, ormlite, activeandroid

are there any significant differences in terms of speed, scalability, ... between theese two ORM solution for Android SQLite - ORMlite vs. ActiveAndroid? First one is free, second is commercial and thus paid. What is better to use and why?

Thanks

Hmyzak

Comment: thank you for asking this question.

Answer (score 10):

ActiveAndroid is now free and open-source.

http://pardom.github.com/ActiveAndroid/

Answer (score 9):

Having tried both, I'd recommend ORMLite. Not only is it free, but it's open source, and as far as I can tell it's also under much more intensive development. It's way better documented, has more samples available... there are many reasons not to use ActiveAndroid, and a couple of them are outlined in this blog post by one of the ORMLite contributors:

http://tumblr.com/ZlYYFy6M_vOf